# Where can I ask for identification of a piece/composer? (Where to ask stuff you can't ask here)

Tags: discussion

I see that it is off-topic to ask a question about identifying a "song".

Specifically

> and it is not about...
>
> identifying a song, genre, instrument, etc.

Where could one ask such a question?

Particularly in this day-and-age of horrible music meta-data, where listeners no longer get liner notes or physical packaging, it can be a mystery as to what piece/composer a track is.  Is there an existing stack exchange site where one can ask this question?  Should we consider allowing it on Musical Practice & Performance?

Thanks.

The piece I wanted to ask about is this (just to give an example)

First track on "Gregorian Chant: The Definitive Collection" by "Benedictine Monks of Santo Domingo de Silos"
Track Title "Mass Of The Angels - Kyrie VIII Mode V"
Who is the composer?  Approximate year?

Audio CD (August 26, 2008)

Label: Milan Records

ASIN: B001BWQABO

Links
http://open.spotify.com/track/7id0Ug2l2ZeKEU56ZmZEMQ

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001E780YG/ref=dm_mu_dp_trk1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001E780YG)

http://www.allmusic.com/performance/kyrie-mq0001228863

Comment: Probably on the music fan SE when it gets into beta. You can sign up for the proposal and help promote it. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans?referrer=cDnsINxyzUhlGleSE5XxcQ2

Comment: This possibly won't work for this piece of music, but as I think I mentioned in a comment in one of these questions, my first step is to run SoundHound, which dies an amazing recognition job.

Comment: you can try the chat